# How to start an unelevated process from from an elevated process

Tags: c#, process-elevation

My application might be running with elevated privileges (it's an app launcher) and I need to launch other application with standard privileges (so that it's not running as admin).

My application is not a setup.

How can I do that?
I need to both launch Executables and document files.

Thanks.

Comment: What special features do you require that force your host application to have Administrator rights?  You shouldn't use Administrator unless you need to, and when you do you should impersonate those rights.  Less security risk. But calling a `Process` should automatically load without Administrator.

Comment: I don't think this will work... the permissions will likely cascade down to the other apps.

Comment: @0A0D If he does the Impersonation method when he requires the rights it will, but also if he starts a separate process then the other application should force him into standard unless he request Administrator.

Comment: Yeah, iirc processes started from an elevated host inherit the elevated token; you'd need to explicitly impersonate a non elevated user before launching it.

Comment: So, is there any solution? Unfortunately there are situations where I need the application to be run as admin.